# Why does my Tkinter Python code not work as I expected?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    pw = ''
    passwordCorrect = False

    window = Tk()

    instructionLabel = Label(window,text='Enter your password:')
    entryBox = Entry(window)
    def checkPassword():
        if entryBox.get() == 'password':
            global passwordCorrect
            passwordCorrect = True

    confirmButton = Button(window,text='Confirm',command=checkPassword)

    instructionLabel.pack()
    entryBox.pack()
    confirmButton.pack()
    window.mainloop()

    if passwordCorrect:
        print('Access granted')
    else:
        print('Access denied')
main()
```

When I close the window I always get the message 'Access denied' (expecting 'Access granted'), even if I enter 'password' into the entry box and press the button. What am I missing? Much obliged.

Comment: Remove `global passwordCorrect`.

Comment: What are you expecting?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to make `passwordCorrect` global in your `main` function. Your `main` function has its own local `passwordCorrect` variable that's different from the global one.

If you're using python 3, you can alternatively change `global passwordCorrect` to `nonlocal passwordCorrect` so that the `checkPassword` function uses the variable defined in `main`.